# Finding the longest Collatz sequence cycle

Tags: java, performance, array, homework

I wrote a program to calculate [Collatz sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Cycles) for initial numbers between 1 and a given integer `i`, then find the one with the largest cycle length.  My code is pretty fast, but I want to increase the speed more.  Please have a look at my code and if there are any changes to made in my code to make it faster.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class asgn {
public static void main(String args[]){
long i,j,n,max=0, pos=0, x,y;
long count=0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the positive integer:");
while(sc.hasNextLong())
{x=System.currentTimeMillis();
 i= sc.nextLong();
long arr[] = new long [50000000];

 for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
{
n=j;
count = 0;
while(n!=1)
{
if(n<50000000)
{if(arr[(int)(n-1)]!=0)
{ count=count+arr[(int)(n-1)];
break;
}}

if(n%2==0)
{n=n/2;
count++;
}
else
{
n = (3*n)+1;
count++;
}
}
if(j<50000000)
arr[(int)(j-1)]=count;
if(count>max)
{max=count; pos=j;}
count=0;
}
y=System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Maximum cycle length occurs at "+pos+" and the number of steps     involved     "+max+"\n Total time taken is "+(y-x)+"milliseconds");
break;}}}
```

Comment: What is the definition of the cycle length?

Comment: Avoiding the use of indentation, spaces, comments, and descriptive variable names won't make your code any faster.

Comment: @ChrisWue From `n = (3*n)+1;` and `n=n/2;` I deduce that the problem is about Collatz sequence cycles.

Answer (score 7):

## Formatting

## USE PROPER INDENTATION - Please!

If you're using Eclipse, press Ctrl + Shift + F.

If you're using Netbeans or IntelliJ, press Alt + Shift + F.

If you're not using any IDE, **start doing so!**

---

#### Braces

Once your code is properly formatted it can be seen that you're not using braces here:

```
if (j < 50000000)
    arr[(int) (j - 1)] = count;
```

It is especially important to use braces when you're code's not formatted properly, as it is easy to accidentally add an extra statement inside the `if`, which would cause unexpected results.

```
if (j < 50000000) {
    arr[(int) (j - 1)] = count;
}
```

---

#### Close Scanner

Scanners should be closed when they have been used. `sc.close();` at the end of your program will take care of that.

---

#### Unnecessary outer `while`

Your outermost `while` "loop" is only executed once because there is a `break;` at the end of it. This could be an `if` instead and the `break;` at the end removed.

---

#### Use the length of the array

```
if (j < 50000000) {
```

and

```
if (n < 50000000) {
```

Should instead be:

```
if (j < arr.length) {
```

and

```
if (n < arr.length) {
```

respectively.

---

#### Slight simplification

```
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    n = n / 2;
    count++;
}
else {
    n = (3 * n) + 1;
    count++;
}
```

Can be written as:

```
n = (n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : (3 * n) + 1);
count++;
```

Or at least, if you don't like the conditional operator (`... ? ... : ...`), use the `if-else` for `n` but do `count++` before or after the if/else.

---

#### Variables

Your naming leaves some things to be desired. `x` and `y` for example should be named `startTime` and `endTime`, the current names makes it sound like it is related to coordinates, which it is not.

The only variable with any meaning is `max` and `count`. It is hard to tell what kind of max `max` is though, naming it `maxCycles` would make that clearer.

As for your other variables, `long i, j, n, pos`, I certainly cannot tell what they're used for without looking at your code for a while. These variable names tell me *absolutely nothing!*

To get a better overlook of the variables, it is better to declare the variables as close to their usage as possible. `y` (`endTime`) is declared at the top, but not used until the end of the method.

---

#### Extract Method

Your main method is doing way too many things right now.

Extract parts of your code to different methods:

For example, your entire `while (n != 1)` loop can be extracted to a `determineCycles` method.

---

#### Speed Improvement

Currently you're saving the result of one calculation into your array, and while that's a good start you are missing out on some values you can use.

Let's take the example of `3`. The sequence is: `3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1`

The only result you are storing from this operation is `3 --> 7`. But you have also found out that `10` has the value `7 - 1`, `5` has the value `7 - 2`, `16` has the value `7 - 3` and so on... Your algorithm would increase significantly in speed if you were also storing these intermediate values.

Answer (score 3):

### In addition to Simon's answer

#### Use the length of the array

Store the length of the array in a `long` and compare against this `long`, in this way you won't need to check each time for the length of the array.

```
long arr[] = new long[500000];
long arrayLength = arr.length;
```

so

```
if (j < arr.length) {
```

should be instead

```
if (j < arrayLength) {
```

and so on.

#### Speed

The fastest way (at least in java) for checking if a number is odd or even, is to look at the least significant bit of the number. If the least significant bit is 0 then and only then the number is `even`.

So using Simon's simplification this results in:

```
n = ((n & 1) == 0 ? n / 2 : (3 * n) + 1);
```

which had given me for the given n = 200000L repeating 100 times these results:

Your version as is: 3099 ms

Version using bit check: 1820 ms